# CMake "namespaced" includes

Tags: c++, cmake

In Python, a module (or package) represents a namespace for other modules.
So for example for this tree

```
package
├── core
│   ├── core.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── extensions
│   ├── extensions.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utils.py
```

If I would want to import `core.py` I would do:

```py
from package.core import core
```

*(assuming `package` is in PYTHONPATH)*
This is useful to avoid namespace clashes.

How can I mimic that behaviour so I would be able to include `core.hpp` like this

```cpp
#include <package/core/core.hpp>
```

with CMake?

Another requirement would be that each subdirectory has it's own `CMakeLists.txt` so the root cmake **does not** know what headers or sources would be included.

C++ layout should look like this

```
package
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── core
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── core.cpp
│   └── core.hpp
├── extensions
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── extensions.cpp
│   └── extensions.hpp
└── utils
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── utils.cpp
    └── utils.hpp
```

P.S.
I saw `target_include_directories`, though it adds the whole directory to the compiler search path and I don't want this since my IDE (CLion) shows non related files there.

Comment: "it adds the whole directory to the compiler search path and I don't want this" This is just standard compiler behavior, there simply isn't a flag to add individual files to the compiler search path. The only way around that is by manually creating the a directory structure with only the files you want to be there in a custom build target and then adding that directory with target_include_directories. But that is a lot of work for not much gain.

Comment: Note: do not use `<package/core/core.hpp>` for your own header files. Use `"package/core/core.hpp"`. You could use relative paths. For example, `core.cpp` could include `extensions.hpp` with `#include "../extensions/extensions.hpp"`

Comment: @JohnHanley I am writing a library.

Comment: Using `<...>` for include files has a meaning. Do not use the style for third-party libraries. Use double-quotes. Your files are not part of the system libraries - unless that is actually what you are writing. Anyways do what you want, this is only a comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley `<...>` does not have "meaning" as far as the standard is concerned, other than the fact that `"..."` searches in a couple more locations (typically, relative paths) before falling back to `<...>`. Some styles/guidelines may impart such meaning, but it is not at all uncommon for styles/guidelines to suggest or mandate using `<...>` for all third-party libraries (including non-system ones, whatever "system" would mean in this context).

Comment: @You - I like how you add `other than the fact ...`. It does make a difference to experienced developers.

Comment: @JohnHanley That other fact happens to be implementation-defined handwaving, and in no way implies "do not use `<...>` for third-party libraries". There are about as many ways to draw the line between `<...>` and `"..."` as there are "experienced developers", I'd reckon; including "third-party libraries", "only standard library headers", and "my particular definition of what constitutes a 'system' header".

Comment: @You - There are various opinions on this matter. K&R is not some names I know from a book. I was on the AT&T Bell Labs team that wrote C, Unix, and most of the tools. I spent 15 years in C/C++ compiler/linker/debugger development. Since this could be a never-ending thread of opinions that are off-topic, I will not comment further.

Answer (score 2):

All the major C++ compilers use a include directory specification mechanism where you tell it directories you want it to search under.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html
- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#include-path-management
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories

If you want to be able to `#include <package/core/core.hpp>`, then you will need to create a directory structure where `core.hpp` is in a directory named `core`, which is in a directory named `package`, and then tell the compiler that it should search under the directory containing `package` (see [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)). If you have other things in the directory containing `package` that you don't want to findable by the search, then you'll need to create an additional intermediate directory and put `package` under that one, and tell the compiler to search under that intermediate directory instead.

> Another requirement would be that each subdirectory has it's own CMakeLists.txt so the root cmake does not know what headers or sources would be included.

Just call `target_include_directories` in the subdirectory's CMakeLists.txt. If you care about that kind of thing, presumably, you're already defining each subdirectory's targets inside their corresponding CMakeLists.txt file.

It sounds to me like you could do with some conventions. Here's an unsolicited suggestion: [the Pitchfork Layout spec](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs).

Comment: "create an additional intermediate directory" seems like an ugly hack... What does C++ users do to avoid namespace clashes? I want to avoid being like Qt (QString QJson **QQmlObject what?!**)

Comment: It is not an ugly hack, but the "idiomatic" way to do it in C++. And unfortunately, it is up to the developer to keep namespace name and directory in sync. Take boost::lexical_cast as an example... https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html. It requires including <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>.

Comment: Also it does not comply with "Another requirement would be that each subdirectory has it's own CMakeLists.txt so the root cmake does not know what headers or sources would be included."

Comment: @ניר It's still possible to do meet this requirement with the approach described, but the file paths get a bit long: e.g. for `core` put `core.hpp` at `package_cpp/core/include/package/core/core.hpp` and use `target_include_directories(mypackage_core PUBLIC include)` in `package_cpp/core/CMakeLists.txt` and you'll get access to the include dir when doing `target_link_libraries(... PRIVATE mypackage_core)` anywhere in your project (alternatively with `PUBLIC` instead of `PRIVATE` visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I mimic that behaviour so I would be able to include core.hpp like this #include <package/core/core.hpp>

CMake has nothing to do with it - CMake does *not* compile your code. Compiler does.

With CMake, you can *copy* the header `core.hpp` file into a directory that contains directory structure `package/core` that you would first create. That sounds like an overkill.

> though it adds the whole directory to the compiler search path and I don't want this since my IDE (CLion) shows non related files there.

So make a separate directory with the include files. Assuming you want `each subdirectory has it's own CMakeLists.txt` you would do:

```
package_cpp/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── core
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt   // target_include_directories(... inc)
│   ├── core.cpp
│   └── inc
           package
              core
                core.hpp
├── extensions
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt   // target_include_directories(... inc)
│   ├── extensions.cpp
│   └── inc
           package
               extensions
                     extensions.hpp
└── utils
    ├── CMakeLists.txt    // target_include_directories(... inc)
    ├── utils.cpp
    └── inc
          package
             utils
                utils.hpp
```

Related https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1204r0.html#src-dir .

Comment: Yet another reason why C++ should get it's stuff together.

Comment: @ניר arguably, this is not even C++ (the core language)'s fault. C++ doesn't specify how include resolution works. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include and see all the places where it says "_implementation-defined_". A lot of people don't use languages because they think they like their aesthetics, or usability, but for what the language enables them to do (or some tradeoff between those values. Ex. stay close to hardware while building abstractions). Think bigger. A lot of people think it's immature to complain about "little things" like this.